# Why can I not store a negative value in a byte variable?

Tags: c#, byte

I am converting code that works in Java but not in C#

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
this.buffer[((int)this.count & 0x3F)] = -128;
```

This generates a compile time error "Constant value '-128' cannot be converted to a 'byte'." How can I store a negative number for a byte?

Comment: A `byte` in C# is an _unsigned_ 8-bit integer.

Comment: @JohnWillemse you should make that an answer, I would upvote it.

Comment: what is the alternative to this ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `byte` data type in Java is *signed* (-128–127). The equivalent data type in C# is `sbyte`.

So the equivalent C# code is as follows:

```
sbyte[] buffer = new sbyte[64];
buffer[..] = -128;
```

If you want an array of *unsigned* bytes (0–255), the `byte` with the same bit pattern as the `sbyte` -128 is 128 (0x80).

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
buffer[..] = 128;
```

*See also:* [Integral Types Table (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx)

Comment: To supplement, you can of course also force the cast to happen. This is done like so (when `buffer` is a `byte[]`): **`buffer[index] = unchecked((byte)(-128));`** The `unchecked(...)` part can be left out when two conditions are met: _1:_ The value to be cast is **not** a compile-time constant, and _2:_ The code is **not** compiled with [`/checked` compiler option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h25wtyxf.aspx). So in these cases you would just say `buffer[index] = (byte)nonConstant;`.

Answer (score 18):

In C#, a `byte` represents an *unsigned* 8-bit integer, and can therefore not hold a negative value (valid values range from `0` to `255`). An alternative is `sbyte`, which is a *signed* 8-bit integer (valid values from `-128` to `127`).