# Why does this code not produce negative values? С#

Tags: c#

I am writing a binary parser in Python. I based it on this repository written in C#.
The original has the following code:

```
return (byte) (byte.MaxValue - b - index - 1);
```

**This code never returns negative values.**

*for example, if b = 254, index = 47, the result will be 209
even though 255 - 254 - 47 -1 = (-47)*

I'm not a C# expert, could you please explain why this is the result?

Comment: As well as the answer that byte is unsigned, it's worth noting that C# is unchecked by default, so will allow you to [underflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) without throwing an exception. That's why your getting 209: The result has wrapped and 256 - 47 is 209.

Comment: I understood and solved the problem by making my "own underflow" if result is negative. 256 + (-47)
thanks!

Answer (score -2):

In C#, a `byte` represents an unsigned 8-bit integer, and can therefore not hold a negative value (valid values range from 0 to 255). An alternative is `sbyte`, which is a signed 8-bit integer (valid values from -128 to 127).

Answer taken from;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14939340/4506812

Comment: If there's an existing answer on Stack Overflow, vote to close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: I tried, didn't let me link the article.

Comment: This question needs slightly more information, namely C#'s default unchecked behaviour.